# convert selected columns at once to integer in R in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Quick question - How to convert all (or some: e.g. `cols=1:5`) columns at once (in one line) to another type (lets say integer), using `dplyr`.

A data to play with: `df  <- diamonds %>% slice(1:3) %>% select  (5:10)`

NB:
I know how to do it in `data.table`:

```
dt <- df %>% data.table; 
cols=1:5
dt[ , (cols):=lapply(.SD, as.integer), .SDcol=cols]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `across` to apply same function to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(all_of(cols), as.integer))
#In old version we use `mutate_at`
#df %>%  mutate_at(all_of(cols), as.integer)

#  depth table price     x     y     z
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#1    61    55   326     3     3  2.43
#2    59    61   326     3     3  2.31
#3    56    65   327     4     4  2.31
```

Using `all_of` is not required but it is a good practice to use it when we use variables which are not present in the dataframe.